# How to prove Delaunay triangulation is planar?

Tags: computational-geometry

Can somebody tell me how to prove this ? The graph of delaunay triangulation looks like planar. But how to prove it?

Comment: Does this not hold by definition?  A triangulation (any triangulation) of a point set S is usually defined as the tesselation of its convex hull into non-overlapping triangles such that the triangles cover the convex hull and that all triangles' vertices coincide with points of S.  Alternatively, you could consider a triangulation to be a maximal set of non-crossing edges between the points of S.  Again, planarity follows directly from the definition.

Comment: @weasel-PeterPalfrader: but what if you define Delaunay to be the dual of  Voronoi, i.e. without explicit reference to a triangulation ?

Comment: I think asking for mathematical proofs make this not a programming problem but a maths one. http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Triangles can overlap. I made lot of buggy triangulations :-) As Yves stated, Delaunay triangulation is dual of Voronoi diagram, which is enough to show non overlapping property. Delaunay edge is segment between neighbouring Voronoi points. Since they are neighbouring it is not possible for other segment to cross it.

Answer (score 1):

In a naive way, you can say that the [Delaunay Triangulation(or Delaunay Graph)](http://web.mit.edu/alexmv/Public/6.850-lectures/lecture09.pdf) DG(P) of a planar set of points P always follows the [Euler's Formula for planarity of graphs](http://www.math.caltech.edu/~2014-15/2term/ma006b/09%20Planar2.pdf):

```
|Faces (including the unbounded face)| + |Vertices| = |Edges| + 2.
```

Hence DG(P) is planar.

Comment: This is not a valid argument: In order to talk about faces you already need planarity. So your argument is circular.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the answer by @Zoham is correct as it can only be used to disprove a graph's planarity.

You can prove this by contradiction. Assume that you have a circle `(a, b, c)` and without loss of generality, some edge `(x, y)` crosses `(a, b)`. We know that neither `x` or `y` can be inside circle `(a, b, c)`. If the circle containing `x, y` (namely `C'`) has a center outside `(a, b, c)` then it's easy to see why `C'` contains either `a` or `b` and hence the contradiction.
If the `C'` has a center (namely `O'`) inside `(a, b, c)`, again W.L.O.G. the biggest such circle is the one with `xy` for its diameter. Use this fact and that either `O'a` or `O'b` is less than `xy/2` to show that `C'` will contain either `a` or `b`.

also check this link with another approach: [link](https://ics.uci.edu/%7Egoodrich/teach/geom/notes/DT.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

**Proof via duality:**

1. The Voronoi diagram is a planar graph; the Voronoi cells are convex polygons tiling the plane (some of which are unbounded).
2. The dual graph of a planar graph is planar.
3. The Delaunay triangulation is the dual graph of the Voronoi diagram.